# Floating floats inside float?

Tags: css, css-float

I know the title of the question sounds absolutely weird but I had no idea what else to call it.

First off I have a grid layout where I want my `.search-wrapper` to be 50% wide and floated right. In my demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQSBR/2/) the entire `.search-wrapper` has a green background color. It's important that this element stays the way it is because it should fit into my grid.

Inside this `.search-wrapper` I have a searchbox and a button both floated side by side. This is just how I want it to be. So the `#search-button` should be floated left and the `input` should be aligned right to it.

However the thing I can't achieve is how to float both - the `#search-button` and the ´input`to the right inside the outer container`.search-wrapper`.

The current status …

[image]

The way I'd like it to be …

[image]

Here is a demo of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mQSBR/2/
Any ideas on that? Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can do a `margin-left: 50px` on the inner-most `fieldset` to shove it to the right. You don't need to be floatin' all over the place like that. It's going to turn into a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this, if this is the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mQSBR/9/ [EDIT]

```
div.search { width: 180px; float: right; } /* fix to 180px wide, float to right */
```

also add:

```
.search-wrapper {
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

so the wrapper won't go past the .search div when resizing.

Comment: @Daedalus right, IE had moved it past the div. A `word-space: no-wrap;` could fix this behaviour.

Comment: This displays far to the right margin in FF13. EDIT: The last edit mitigate that to a degree; now the red square is about midway in the middle of the green.

Comment: @JaredFarrish really? I can see a 10px space, I guess that's okay.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I dunno, we're seeing a different screen effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in the updated jsfiddle

```
<div class="wrapper search-wrapper">
  <div class="search">
    <form action="/" method="get">
      <fieldset>
         <input type="text" name="s" id="search-box" value="" class="" placeholder="Search this platform …">
            <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
 </div>
```

​

```
.search-wrapper {
width: 50%;
float: right;
background:green;
margin-top:1em;
```

}

```
#search-box {
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
color: transparent;
height: 20px;
float: right;
```

}

```
#search-button {
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
color: transparent;
float: right;
background-color:red;
background-position: center -36px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

​

[Right align of search box/button](http://jsfiddle.net/mQSBR/18/)


Also, my proposal is to use placeholder attribute of an element instead of overflowing label

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
.search {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<fieldset style="margin-left: 20%">
  <div class="input-inside-label">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mQSBR/3/

Made a couple of edits to compensate for the `overflow-x` scroll bar:

```
#search-button {
    ...
    margin-left: -20px;
    ...
}
.input-inside-label {
    ...
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mQSBR/7/